# Как менять урл при скролле по блокам?

Tags: javascript, url, прокрутка

Подскажите плз, как менять урл при скролле.
Например, изначально урл такой: sait.name, скролим до второго блока, урл меняется на: sait.name/?page2, скроллим до третьего блока, урл меняется на: sait.name/?page3
В обратную сторону меняется соответственно.
Решение через хэш не подходит.

Помогите, хоть в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на HTML5 History API и методы `pushState()` и `replaceState()`, они умеют такое делать

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API#Добавление_и_изменение_записей_истории](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)